# сделать так, чтобы кнопки не детектились

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

использую `forward` для пересылки сообщений/фото, но всё рушит `KeyboardButton` , т.к. это по факту сообщение и оно пересылается тоже, можно ли сделать чтобы сообщение кнопок не детектились?

```
if message.text == ("/send ")
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID, "@" + message.chat.username) 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '%s, сообщение было отправлено '%message.chat.username)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

тут я пытался сделать по типу: /send текст или же: /send и сообщение

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `callback` кнопки. Или же вырезать из Вашего сообщения ключевое слово:

```js
message = 'send Наше сообщение состоящее из слов'
words = message.split(' ') # Разделяем слова на список по пробелу

index = words.index('send')
words.pop(index)

message = ' '.join(words) # Собираем список обратно в текст

# P.S код не тестил, но думаю принцип понятен(существуют более лучшие решения)
```

Но я назову это костылем, имхо